# image inside a multirow: problems with the vertical space

Tags: tables, graphics, multirow

I have a problem when including an image inside a table using the multirow option. My problem comes from the vertical space dedicated to this row. As you can see in the picture included, the image gets more vertical space than the dedicated to the row. 
[image: As you can see the image is not fully included]

Here, I put the latex code I have used for generating the above picture:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}c ccccc}
\toprule 
& & $1024 \times 1024$ & $512 \times 512$ &$256 \times 256$ & $128 \times 128$ & $64  \times 64$ \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=.15\textwidth{../images/BestViews/PVMTooth/3.PVMTooth.dir/1024x1024-0613}}& Time & 254.2 & 57.63 & 17.61 & 4.77& 2.07  \tabularnewline
& Best Entropy & 3.0 & 3.49 & 4.28 & 5.88 & 8.56 \tabularnewline
& Worst Entropy & 1.23 & 1.52 &1.9&2.6 & 4.67 \tabularnewline
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The best and worst views according to our measure for different image size.}
\label{table:BB:BestAndWorstNumbers}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6):

Give some vertical space substituting `\tabularnewline` with `\\[1.25ex]`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}c ccccc}
\toprule
& & $1024 \times 1024$ & $512 \times 512$ &$256 \times 256$ & $128 \times 128$ & $64  \times 64$ \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=.15\textwidth,width=1cm]{../images/BestViews/PVMTooth/3.PVMTooth.dir/1024x1024-0613}}
& Time & 254.2 & 57.63 & 17.61 & 4.77& 2.07  \\[1.25ex]
& Best Entropy & 3.0 & 3.49 & 4.28 & 5.88 & 8.56 \\[1.25ex]
& Worst Entropy & 1.23 & 1.52 &1.9&2.6 & 4.67 \\[1.25ex]
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The best and worst views according to our measure for different image size.}
\label{table:BB:BestAndWorstNumbers}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to give all the spacing at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}c ccccc}
\toprule
& & $1024 \times 1024$ & $512 \times 512$ &$256 \times 256$ & $128 \times 128$ & $64  \times 64$ \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=.15\textwidth,width=1cm]{../images/BestViews/PVMTooth/3.PVMTooth.dir/1024x1024-0613}}
& Time & 254.2 & 57.63 & 17.61 & 4.77& 2.07  \\
& Best Entropy & 3.0 & 3.49 & 4.28 & 5.88 & 8.56 \\
& Worst Entropy & 1.23 & 1.52 &1.9&2.6 & 4.67 \\[3.75ex]
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The best and worst views according to our measure for different image size.}
\label{table:BB:BestAndWorstNumbers}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `cellspace` package, that ensures a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and symmetrically between its bottom and the top of the below cell. It works with most column types but not with \multirow. To activate this feature it suffices to write an S before the type of one column ; I chose the text (second) column that I changed to `l` (I like it better that way) and adapted the minimal spacing via a command defined in preamble. Of course if you have may tables with different image heights, you'll have to determine its value each time, but it's only 1 line to write per table, so I hope you'll find it less time-consuming.

Anyway here is an example. I centred the numerical value with respect to the decimal dot with `numprint` when necessary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}%[draft]
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\hfill}N{3}{2}<{\hfill}}
\newcommand*\cellspacelimit[1]{\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{#1}\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{#1}}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\cellspacelimit{10pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c Sl  DDDcc}%{m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace
& & {$1024 \times 1024$} & {$512 \times 512$} &{$256 \times 256$} & $128 \times 128$ & $64  \times 64$ \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=.2\textwidth]{AliceSteadman.png}} & Time & 254.2 & 57.63 & 17.61 & 4.77& 2.07  \tabularnewline
& Best Entropy & 3.0 & 3.49 & 4.28 & 5.88 & 8.56 \tabularnewline
& Worst Entropy & 1.23 & 1.52 &1.9&2.6 & 4.67 \tabularnewline
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The best and worst views according to our measure for different image size.}
\label{table:BB:BestAndWorstNumbers}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But, these kind of solutions are time-consuming depending on the number of tables that you have and also on the number of different images you have to include inside the tables. I would like to find some automatic solution to my problem, although the proposals you have done solutionate my problem. I will be waiting for a less time-consuming solution. But, in any case, thanks for yours proposals.

Comment: @EvaMonclús: I've entirely changed my answer, which is now less time-consuming, I think.

Comment: My main problem is that the dimensions of the images are different. So, in the end, I have to manually adjust the size of them or use your first answer.

Comment: ??? The original dimension of my image also was different; it was scaled through `height=.2\textwidth`. Adjustment can be achieved with a suitable value of `cellspacelimit`. You also could play with `\arraystretch`, but the rows then are no more vertically centred. Another solution would be tu insert in a cell an invisible rule (0pt thickness) but itlonger to determine the exact values of its depth and height so that the cell remains vertically centred.